# Which city is this in DayZ Standalone?

Tags: dayz-standalone

I couldn't find the name of this city. Can anyone help?

[image: Screenshot of City in a Valley]

[image: Closer look at a street lined with buildings]

Answer (score 3):

I believe this city is [Novodmitrovsk](http://dayz.gamepedia.com/Novodmitrovsk)

I believe you are sitting on top of the City Hall tower maybe?

[image]